# the usage of !important in css for responsive layout

Tags: html, css

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
.box{
   color:orange !important;
}
}

.box{
   color:red;
}
```

In mobile the `.box` will be blue, but without the `!important` it will not work. It's ok not to put the `!important` if the property isn't declared outside of the media queries bracket. How do I avoid using `!important`?

Comment: Have you declared the `red` after `@media` ?

Comment: I guess the 'blue' should be 'orange' in your post as per your code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your media rule below to desktop css rules

```
.box{
   color:red;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
    .box{
        color:blue; /* should be blue as per OP */
     }
}
```

Comment: seriously? why I don't know bout this?!

Comment: it is the way css parse the rules

Answer (score 0):

just change the order from

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
    .box{
        color:blue !important;
    }
}

.box{
   color:red;
}
```

to

```
.box{
   color:red;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
    .box{
        color:blue;
    }
}
```

Because if you use the same `selector`, the `style` that will be used is the newer one (from top to down)